# How to remove blank line in CSV file in php

Tags: php

I m trying to fetch data from xml file then write it in CSV file.In generated file its put so many blank line after each record .

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=spreadsheet.xls");
$url = 'test.xml'; // xml file location with file name
if (file_exists($url)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    echo 'item_no' . "\t" . 'description' . "\t" . 'price' . "\t" . 'base_qty' . "\t" . 'var_qty' . "\t" . 'base_price_1' . "\t\n";
    foreach ($xml->record as $books) {
        $array_count = count($books);
        for ($key = 0; $key < $array_count; $key++) {
            echo $books->item_no[$key]."\t" . $books->description[$key]."\t" . $books- >price[$key]."\t" . $books->base_qty[$key] . "\t" . $books->var_qty[$key] . "\t" . $books->base_price_1[$key] . "\t" . "\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `\n` is not printed at the last record

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=spreadsheet.xls");
$url = 'test.xml'; // xml file location with file name
$output = "";
if (file_exists($url)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $output.= 'item_no' . "\t" . 'description' . "\t" . 'price' . "\t" . 'base_qty' . "\t" . 'var_qty' . "\t" . 'base_price_1' . "\t\n";
    foreach ($xml->record as $books) {
        $array_count = count($books);
        for ($key = 0; $key < $array_count; $key++) {
            $output.= $books->item_no[$key]."\t" . $books->description[$key]."\t" . $books- >price[$key]."\t" . $books->base_qty[$key] . "\t" . $books->var_qty[$key] . "\t" . $books->base_price_1[$key] . "\t" . "\n";
        }
    }
    echo rtrim($output);
}
?>
```

Comment: I thnk somthng is wrong in for loop.e.g there 3 records found in foreach ..then for first record FOR loop is execute 4 time. so for first record there are only one record so ..it will left 3 blank line?I m just assuming not sure

Comment: `if($key<$array_count-1)`

Comment: @Aanshi, try this same code again. I just updated it for Rogier21

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Thanks, I didn't see that the for condition was a lesser than!

Comment: @Aanshi my solution won't work just yet because you make 2 iterations. What you can do is write all the output to a variable instead to the screen, then strip the last `\n` and then output that.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Now it put space left side also